# Finding the number density of a Fermi gas

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, fermions, bosons, identical-particles

When calculating the number density of a Fermi-Dirac or Bose-Einstein distributed particle:

$$n=\frac{g}{2\pi^3} \int f(\vec{p})d^3p$$

Apparently one can change variables and get

$$n=\frac{g}{2\pi^3} \int dE\frac{E(E^2-m^2)^{1/2}}{e^{(E-\mu)/T}\pm1}$$

But I can't figure out how to do that $d^3p \rightarrow dE$ change! I'm definitely missing some detail... Any help on this will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take, assuming isotropy on p:

$$d^{3}p = 4\pi p^{2}dp, $$

and taking $c = 1$ in the energy-momentum relation:

$$E^{2} = p^{2} + m^{2}. $$

We have:

$$|\frac{dp}{dE}| = \frac{E}{\sqrt{E^{2} - m^{2}}}. $$

Then:

$$d^{3}p = 4\pi p^{2}dp = 4\pi \frac{(E^{2} - m^{2})}{\sqrt{E^{2} - m^{2}}}EdE.$$

So, finally:

$$d^{3}p = 4\pi E\sqrt{E^{2} - m^{2}}dE.$$

Answer (score 1):

The energy $E$ is related to the moment $p$ in the following way (with $c=1$)

$$E=\sqrt{p^2+m^2}\rightarrow p=\sqrt{E^2-m^2}\tag{1}.$$

$d^3p$ is a infinitesimal volume in the $p$-space. Since $f(p)$ depends only in the magnitude of $\vec{p}$, we can use spherical coordinates, so $$d^3p=p^2\sin\theta \,dp\,d\theta\,d\phi$$

$$n=\frac{g}{2\pi^3}\int f(p)d^3p=\frac{g}{2\pi^3}\int_0^\pi \sin\theta\, d\theta\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi \int_0^\infty f(p)p^2dp=\frac{g}{2\pi^3}4\pi\int_0^\infty f(p)p^2 dp.$$

Now, from $(1)$,

$$\frac{dp}{dE}=\frac{E}{\sqrt{E^2-m^2}}\rightarrow dp=\frac{E\,dE}{\sqrt{E^2-m^2}},$$

and the Fermi-Dirac/Bose-Einstein distributions are

$$f(E)=\frac{1}{e^{(E-\mu)/kT}\pm1},$$

so

$$n=\frac{g}{2\pi^3}4\pi\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{e^{(E-\mu)/kT}\pm1} (E^2-m^2)\frac{E\,dE}{\sqrt{E^2-m^2}}=\frac{g}{2\pi^3}4\pi\int_0^\infty dE\frac{E\sqrt{E^2-m^2}}{e^{(E-\mu)/kT}\pm1}.$$

I don't know what happend with the $4\pi$ term, but I think it must be there.